# Angular Service worker incorrectly intercepting http redirects (302)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, service-worker, angular-service-worker

In my project, i am using Angular and Spring boot. My service worker is generating by Angular when i build my project.

I use external service (auth2) and my back-end redirecting to login page when session times out. This works perfectly fine without the service worker enabled, however with the service worker this fails.

To my observation, the mode of the Request is changed from navigate to cors.

Without SW:

Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate

With SW:

Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors

When active service worker, i have this exception :

Access to fetch at 'https://authentication-url.com/...' (redirected from 'https://my-w
ebsite.com/file-request.json') from origin 'https://my-website.com' has been blocked by
CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque
response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource
with CORS disabled.

I tried adding ngsw-bypass=true query param to the redirect, but that did not help.

Can you help me ? I search on web but i found nothing on this problem with Angular service worker.

Answer (score 1):

In the back-end try add the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to the cors default headers. That means that the server isn't given access to your app. I had the same problem with angular and django and i added `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to the cors defaul headers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you about 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' but I use Spring boot and i configure Cors in global. [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html) I don't think the problem is Cors problem because is working when service worker enabled